# Gradle. Change/disable task on dependent project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have project configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':model') //when it is compiled. I need to disable some of its tasks
    ...
```

How to disable some tasks during build on sub-project.

Comment: "project(':model').task.enabled = false" does not work for some reason.

Comment: you need to give a bit more context. Are these your own tasks you want disabled? why do you want them disabled? do you want them disabled in subsequent builds? a task will only run once if its inputs/outputs don't change, so normally gradle will skip a task if 'nothing has changed', which you can control through fixing the input and output of the task.